# CSS Box shadow on 1 side of a div. But without a radius

Tags: css

I'm looking for a way to put a boxshadow on only one side of a div. This code doesn't do what I want (It places a boxshadow on 1 side, but the top and bottom is lighter than than the middle).

```css
.myDiv {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 0 5px -2px #888;
  box-shadow: 10px 0 5px -2px #888;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

Is there anyway to have the top and bottom be the same transparency as the middle. It seems that the problem with boxshadow, it that it uses a radius.

My div has an opacity of 0.5 and I want it to fade away as it gets further to the right, but using the code above, it works for the middle part of the div, but at the top and bottom there is a clear edge.

Comment: Perhaps a demo of the issue..?

Comment: I *think* you are asking for a **gradient** box-shadow....what is this supposed to look like..because those don't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a pseudo-element with a linear gradient background

```css
  .myDiv {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.myDiv::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #888, transparent);
```

```html
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah....the `opacity` makes this a little harder (which is why I disregarded it)...but that's a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

An idea is to use box-shadow with a pseudo-element, create an overflow and then hide it with a container:

```css
.myDiv {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.content {
  display:inline-block;
  padding-right:10px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.myDiv:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top: -20px;
  bottom: -20px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 0 5px -2px #888;
  box-shadow: 10px 0 5px -2px #888;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="myDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use multiple translucent shadows ;)

```css
.myDiv {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow:   10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                 9px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                 7px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: @TemaniAfif It is a suggestion among other answers here, pseudo can already be used for something else. It also reminds that box-shadow can produce many shadows, not just one ;).  You can of course use as many steps you want and any colors . You can also use a CSS preprocessor  to make the troll live longer ;) This is a very basic example actually that spares pseudos or extra tag